# What to put into try block?

Tags: java, try-catch

What I'm supposed to do is whenever someone puts in a string instead of an integer, such as "two", it should say "You must enter positive numeric data!" instead of a bunch of error messages. I think I have the catch statement figured out, but I'm not sure that to put into try. Here is what I have so far:

```
package loanpaymentfinder;

import java.text.NumberFormat;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class LoanPaymentFinder {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

        NumberFormat num = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();

        double numInputLoan;
        double numInputRate;
        double numInputYears;
        double numMonths;
        double numRateSquared;
        double numOutput;
        double numRatePlusOne;
        boolean finish = false;

        while (true) {

            //Input
            System.out.print("Enter loan amount: ");
            numInputLoan = Double.parseDouble(in.nextLine());
            try {

            } catch (NumberFormatException exception) {
                System.out.println("You must enter positive numeric data!");
                System.out.print("Would you like to calculate again (y/n):");
                String input = in.nextLine();
                if (input.equals("y")) {
                    continue;
                } else if (input.equals("n")) {
                    break;
                }
            }
            System.out.print("Enter rate: ");
            numInputRate = Double.parseDouble(in.nextLine());

            System.out.print("Enter number of years: ");
            numInputYears = Double.parseDouble(in.nextLine());

            //Checks for negitive inputs

            if (numInputLoan <= 0) {
                System.out.println("You must enter positive numeric data!");
                System.out.print("Would you like to calculate again (y/n):");
                String input = in.nextLine();
                if (input.equals("y")) {
                    continue;
                } else if (input.equals("n")) {
                    break;
                }

            } else if (numInputRate <= 0) {
                System.out.println("You must enter positive numeric data!");
                System.out.print("Would you like to calculate again (y/n):");
                String input = in.nextLine();
                if (input.equals("y")) {
                    continue;
                } else if (input.equals("n")) {
                    break;
                }
            } else if (numInputYears <= 0) {
                System.out.println("You must enter positive numeric data!");
                System.out.print("Would you like to calculate again (y/n):");
                String input = in.nextLine();
                if (input.equals("y")) {
                    continue;
                } else if (input.equals("n")) {
                    break;
                }
            } else {
                //Math goes here
                numMonths = 12 * numInputYears;
                numInputRate = numInputRate / 1200;
                numRatePlusOne = numInputRate + 1;
                numRateSquared = Math.pow(numRatePlusOne, numMonths);
                numOutput = numRateSquared / (numRateSquared - 1);
                numOutput = numInputRate * numInputLoan * numOutput;

                //Output
                System.out.println("The mounthly payment is:");
                System.out.println(num.format(numOutput));
                System.out.print("Would you like to calculate again (y/n):");
                String input = in.nextLine();
                if (input.equals("y")) {
                    continue;
                } else if (input.equals("n")) {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The Exception-causing code must occur inside the TRY. Also, the amount of code, and the code itself, inside the CATCH is bad practice. I don't have the time to explain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it ;)

```
    try
    {
       numInputLoan = Double.parseDouble (in.nextLine());
    }
    catch(...)
    ...
```

Answer (score 3):

In the try block you put some code that could go wrong. Something you want to try.

Look at this part code you added:

> numInputLoan = Double.parseDouble (in.nextLine());

You want to parse a String to a double, but what if this string contains a 's' for example?
It gives an error because you can't parse a 's' to a double.
So you should TRY to execute it and you might CATCH an error.

conclusion, move numInputLoan = Double.parseDouble (in.nextLine()); to the try block.

Answer (score 1):

Put `numInputLoan = Double.parseDouble (in.nextLine());` in try block.

Your code must be

```
// Input
    System.out.print("Enter loan amount: ");

    try
    {
        numInputLoan = Double.parseDouble(in.nextLine());
    }
```

in.nextLine() returns what you have entered in console, so when you parse it to Double, if it has string, it will give NumberFormatException, so this part goes in try.

and initialize `numInputLoan` also, otherwise you will get compilation error.

Answer (score 1):

What you'll have to put inside the `try` block is the actual attempt at converting the input (`String`) into an `integer`. Contrary to some languages like C#, Java doesn't have an `Int.TryParse(String s)` method, so the result and subsequent handling of your parsing should be enclosed in a `try` so you can deal with faulty input.

That's why

```
numInputLoan = Double.parseDouble (in.nextLine());
```

should be in the `try` block, so that when it fails and throws an `Exception`, the `catch` block can take over.

Answer (score 1):

A try statement is used to catch exceptions that might be thrown as your program executes. You should use a try statement whenever you use a statement that might throw an exception That way, your program won’t crash if the exception occurs.

In your code,this `numInputLoan = Double.parseDouble (in.nextLine());` might throw exception so to avoid crashing your program you should keep this in `try` so that if excpetion occurs then control goes to catch and prevent from crashing.use this way

```
try
{
numInputLoan = Double.parseDouble (in.nextLine());
}
catch(Exception e)
{
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the try block, you put anything that could cause the exception you're checking for. In this case, since you're preparing for the NumberFormatException, you probably want to enclose at least the statement where you call `parseDouble`. Like this:

```
try {
    numInputLoan = Double.parseDouble (in.nextLine());
}
```